# Vim writes to file without having permissions

Tags: files, permissions, vim

```
$ ls sess.vim -lh              
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 11K Feb 26 18:52 sess.vim
```

I want this file to be readable for everyone and writable by no one (except by root). Thus I set its permissions to `644` and ownership to `root:root`.

```
$ echo "text" >> sess.vim      
zsh: permission denied: sess.vim
```

Seems fine. After some changes in vim I do `:w!` (force write) and the file is saved successfully. Now:

```
$ ls sess.vim -lh
-rw-r--r-- 1 MY_USERNAME users 11K Feb 26 19:06 sess.vim
```

Wt.. **Why? How?**

Comment: sounds like you replaced the file and over wrote the old one with a new one, so rather than modifying you deleted and recreated. keeping the same file permissions but exchanging the username for the creator which is now technically your username

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `:w!` in vim is similar to the following:

```
echo 'test' > sess.vim.temp
mv sess.vim.temp sess.vim
```

The `mv` commands only cares about the directory permissions, the permissions of the file are not relevant. This is because you are modifying the directory, not writing to the file. To accomplish your goal, you will also need to adjust the permissions of the directory the file resides in.

Comment: and even more, you can use `:w !sudo tee  %` to write to directory you are not an owner )

Answer (score 1):

This is working because the user and group ownership of the parent directory is your-username:your-group-name

If a user is the owner of a directory and has write permission for that directory he is allowed to remove any file contained in it (regardless of the file's permissions). I suspect vim unlinks (removes) the file it edits and writes a new file with the same filename when :wq! is given.